# Python - Load data of .txt file and save in np.array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm working with the python programming language

Suppose I have a file named "data.txt", written in the format below (the text is already written in the format of np.array):

```
([[0.0000000,   1.0893900,  0.0000000], [0.0000000, 1.0820800,  0.0000000], [0.0000000, 1.0815400,  0.0000000]])
```

How could I load the information from this file and save that data in an np.array variable?

What I need is something like loading the information from the txt file in the form below:

```
variable = np.array([[0.0000000,    1.0893900,  0.0000000], [0.0000000, 1.0820800,  0.0000000], [0.0000000, 1.0815400,  0.0000000]])
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676265/how-to-read-a-text-file-into-a-list-or-an-array-with-python Here is the answer...

Comment: To work arround my problem, i just cleaned the "(", "[", "]", and ")" symbols and use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42857861/load-txt-file-into-numpy-array Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0):

To work arround my problem, i just cleaned the "(", "[", "]", and ")" symbols and use this answer [Load txt file into numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42857861/load-txt-file-into-numpy-array)